# PHP, regex and new line ignoring

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to get **2014, December** from following value

```
<tr>
<th rowspan="2" scope="row">Launch</th>
<td class="ttl"><a href=# onClick="helpW('h_year.htm');">Announced</a></td>
<td class="nfo">2014, December</td>
</tr>
```

And I used the following code to get that without any success

```
preg_match_all("/Announced<\/a><\/td><td class=\"nfo\">(.*?)<\/td>/m", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

I tried **/./s** in place of **x** but no luck. I need your advice.

PS: I cannot use DOM parser because I had already many patterns ready to extract string as per my need using regex.

EDIT:
This now also solved my issue

```
preg_match_all("/(Announced<\/a><\/td>).*?(<td class=\"nfo\">)(.*?)<\/td>/s", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

Comment: Reopened according to your PS statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to add a `\n` character inbetween in your regex.

```
preg_match_all("~Announced<\/a><\/td>\n<td class=\"nfo\">(.*?)<\/td>~m", $input_lines, $output_array);
                                      ^
                                      |
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rF1sU7/5)